# How spark works when a join is followed by a coalesce

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given I have 2 `DataFrame`s `df1` and `df2`

I perform a `join` followed by a `coalesce`

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("id")).coalesce(1)
```

It seems that Spark create 2 stages, and the second stage, where the SortMergeJoin happens, is computed only by one task.

So this unique task need to have both entire dataframes in memory (cf : http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-usage-of-reduce-tasks).

Can you confirm ?

(I'd have expected that the sort use the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` settings and a third additional stage perform the coalesce).

cf DAG

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the confirmation in the book [High Performance Spark](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920046967.do).

> Since tasks are executed on the child partition, the number of tasks
>   executed in a stage that includes a `coalesce` operation is equivalent
>   to the number of partitions in the result RDD of the `coalesce`
>   transformation.